# create product Array which contains product of all elements of Array which are divisible by A[i] without using division operator

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, division

Given an array and find product array where each element of Product Array is computed as follows:

```
B[i] = product of all the element of A which are divisible by A[i]
```

without using the division operator.

for example `A = {2,4,3,7,8}`
product `Array = {32,8,0,0,0}`

I try to  solve using O(n2) approach.for each number I search the array and check whether it is divisible by given number or not using (subtraction operation I performed division) then multiply all these numbers.

```
bool division(int x,int y){
  while(x>=y){
    x=x-y;
  }  
  if(x!=0)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}

int main()
{

  int n=5;
  int A[]={2,4,3,7,8};
  int prod[5];
  int mul=1;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    mul=1;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++) 
    {
      if(i!=j)
      {
         bool isdivisible=division(A[j],A[i]); 
         if(isdivisible==1)
         {
            mul=mul*A[j];
         }
      }
    }
    if(mul!=1)
      prod[i]=mul;
    else
      prod[i]=0;
  }
  for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
    cout<<prod[k]<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: Use % operator then. :)

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @user2182259 Update your attempt in the question. Not in comments.

Comment: What everybody is trying to say: **Edit** your post, and **add** the **code** you have written so far.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal please see my attempt

Comment: @user2182259 So what problem are you facing?

Comment: @user2182259 Is there a range limitation of elements A[i]?

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
std::vector<int> do_stuff(const std::vector<int>& a)
{
    std::vector<int> out(a.size(), 0);
    const int len = a.size();

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        out[i] = 1;

        for (int k=0; k<len; k++)
            if (i != k && a[k] % a[i] == 0)
                out[i] *= a[k];
    }

    return out;
}
```